# Simple select records from two tables

Tags: select

I have 2 tables (table_A has one column products_id & table_B has products_id & state)
My query needs to select, all products_id from table_A join with table_B except these products_id that have state = open.
i tried bellow but it displays records from table_B records only

SELECT * FROM table_A
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT product_id, state FROM table_B WHERE table_A.product_id = e_productBAK1FEB.product_id AND state == 'open'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select table_A.* from table_A 
join table_B on table_A.product_id = table_B.product_id
where table_B.state != 'open'
```

Comment: Doesn't work , displays records from Table_B only. Need to have all data from table_A

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you are only getting data from table_B. `Select *` means select every column from every table in the join. See this sqlfiddle as an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff78b8/1. What database engine are you using?

Comment: I've changed my answer so that you only get the columns from Table_A. Is that what you are trying to get?

Comment: Ι made a new query, seems working as i want so far.
"SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT product_id, state FROM table_B WHERE table_A.product_id = table_B.product_id AND state != 'open' )"